# cudaMemcpy()'s performance not improving after using cudaHostAlloc()

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I have a program that performs BLAS's gemm() subprogram in cuBLAS as follows:

```
size_t m = 10000;
size_t k = 4000;
size_t n = 6000;

// h_A is an m-by-k matrix, h_B is a k-by-n matrix and h_C is a m-by-n matrix.

double *h_C;
cudaHostAlloc((void **)(&h_C), m * n * sizeof(double), cudaHostAllocDefault);

uint64_t t0 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();

CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasCreate(&cublasH));

uint64_t t1 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();

CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)(&d_A), sizeof(double) * m * k));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)(&d_B), sizeof(double) * k * n));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)(&d_C), sizeof(double) * m * n));

uint64_t t2 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();

CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A.data(), sizeof(double) * m * k, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B.data(), sizeof(double) * k * n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

uint64_t t3 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();

CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasDgemm(cublasH, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, k, &alpha, d_A, lda, d_B, ldb, &beta, d_C, ldc));

uint64_t t4 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();

CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, sizeof(double) * m * n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

uint64_t t5 = get_timestamp_in_microsec();
```

The performace is okay except the final `cudaMemcpy()` that moves `d_C` back to `h_C` takes almost 3 seconds:

```
t1-t0: 12.929ms
t2-t1: 0.949ms
t3-t2: 53.256ms
t4-t3: 0.315ms
t5-t4: 2653.57ms
```

After searching SO and other sites, I migrated from `malloc()` to `cudaHostAlloc()` but the above result seems not changing at all.

Any issue in my code or is this performance optimal already?

Comment: Quick experiment: Insert a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after `cublasDgemm()`. How long does the `cudaMemcpy()` take now? If much shorter, then the time of the *asynchronous* GEMM call in your code is being attributed to the *synchronous* `cudaMemcpy()` call. Use the CUDA profiler to avoid these pitfalls.

Comment: @njuffa yes you are correct, now time needed by `cudaMemcpy(DeviceToHost)` is in line with `cudaMemcpy(HostToDevice)` and `cublasDgemm()` now takes ~2600ms. However it does surprise me as docs of `cublasDgemm()` mention nothing about the asynchronicity at all.

Comment: In CUDA device code generally executes asynchronous to host code, that is the whole point. `cublasGemm()` maps to any number of kernels executing on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @njuffa, I inserted `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` right after `CUBLAS_CHECK(cublasDgemm(cublasH, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, k, &alpha, d_A, lda, d_B, ldb, &beta, d_C, ldc));`. The numbers are more reasonable now:

```
t1-t0: 12.826ms
t2-t1: 0.955ms
t3-t2: 52.843ms
t4-t3: 2620.88ms
t5-t4: 36.406ms
```